# Edit and Continue while developing on Azure?

Tags: debugging, azure, build

I wonder if any workaround exists for enabling edit and continue while developing an Azure project? I use the emulator, which states it can only handle AnyCPU and x64 target platforms, but on x64 edit and continue isn't available. About the AnyCPU I don't know if it is possible.

The reason I need this, is because after every change I make to my code (not frontend), the whole WebRole is restarted, and this consumes too much time.

Or if this isn't possible, then is there any way to modify the code without the need of restarting the WebRole in the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

http://kevgriffin.com/unable-to-edit-and-continue-in-windows-azure-web-roles/

Might want to try this.

James

Comment: unfortunately in my csproj file there isn't any <packagewebrole> element. And also, Edit and Continue is not available for some reason for 64 bit applications in general. So I tried configuring my web project for a 32bit (x86) target platform, but after this, when I started debug, the emulator said it only supports x64 and AnyCPU configurations and couldn't start.
So is there any chance to run 32bit targeted projects under a 64bit azure emulator?

Comment: @SzabóBálint I cannot seem to make that answer work either, I have just fired up a test project. Sorry for the misleading information. From what I can work out you can only get Any CPU or 64 bit running. I run my projects with a host hack for and IIS so I we run outside of the emulator, this means for actually changes we just rebuild and off you go on the web project and for full on debug I just attach to the process. That obivously does not answer your question but might give you an alternative to the dev process.